# Selecting value of EXISTS with Poco

Tags: mysql, poco-libraries

I am trying to see if a row exists in a MySQL table with the Poco libraries.

One way of doing this, which works, is:

```
session << "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE Serial=?",
    into(n), // int
    tableName, // string
    use(serial), now;
```

and then check whether `n==0`.

However, a clearer (and faster) way of doing this would be

```
session << "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Serial = ?)",
    into(n),
    tableName,
    use(serial), now;
```

The value of `n` would then be either 0 or 1. This, however, throws an assertion exception at runtime (`!pBinder.isNull()`). This occurs regardless of whether `n` is an `int` or a `bool` (which would be more adequate, since `EXISTS` returns a `BOOLEAN`).

In case the problem was with my binding (as the error would imply, even though this binding is identical to other queries I've done previously), I tried doing this with `RecordSet`, temporarily removing all bindings for this test, then printing it to the screen.

```
session << "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Serial = 'XXX')", now;
RecordSet r(exists);
cout << r;
```

The query and the construction of the `RecordSet` seem to work just fine, but when I try to print to the console, a `Poco::BadCastException` is thrown.

So, can this be done with Poco or do I just have to keep using the `SELECT COUNT(*)` method?

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't use Poco, so I can't comment on that.  However, if you can't manage to get it to work directly, don't resort to `count(*)`, as that's a much slower operation on large tables.  Worst case, you'll want something like:

`select if(exists(select 1 from %s where Serial=?), 1, 0)`

Or whatever other values you'd like to have for `true` and `false`.